# Maven Plugin Execution Order and excluding js files

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have developed the pom.xml to first combine all the js files in the project and then compress the JS file. These 2 steps are two plugin and are in compile phase.

But some how few times puglin execution order is reversed and build fails. In case some one has seen this issue please redirect me to solution.

Secondly, I don't to include the JS in .war which are combined and compressed.

Comment: Please include the relevant section of your pom.xml

Comment: I removed the `[maven-plugin]` which is used for plugin development. But why is this tagged `[maven-assembly-plugin]`?

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer the first part of the question, plugins bound to the same phase are supposed to be executed in the same order as they are listed in the POM and any other behavior should be considered as a but (see [MNG-2258](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258)). But I personally get the expected behavior with Maven 2.2.1.

Answering the second part of the question will be harder without more details:

- what is the structure of your project?
- where are the initial files located?
- what are you using or doing (are you using the [YIU Compressor](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html) of the previous question?)?

  - if yes, do you know that it can deal with [`aggregations`](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html#aggregations) (and thus remove the need for two executions)
- where do you output compressed file?

In other words, give more info please.